# A question on the proof of Cayley's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

This is the proof of Cayley's Theorem in Rotman's book - Advanced Modern Algebra Part 2. [image]

I have a vague in the definition of $\tau_a$. Why did he said "if $a \ne 1$, then $\tau_a$ is not a homomorphism"?

Comment: You may consider that as a side note. It doesn't play any role in the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: What is $\tau_a(1)$, given the definition of $\tau_a$?

Comment: $\tau_a(1)$ is the trivial homomorphism, isn't it?

Comment: @Minh What is the definition of $\tau_a$?

Comment: $\tau_a$ is a map, $\tau_a \colon G \rightarrow G, \tau_a(x) = ax$.

Comment: And if $\tau_a(x)=ax$, then $\tau_a(1)=$?

Comment: If $\tau_a(x)=ax$ then $\tau_a(1)=x$ for all $x \in G$.

Comment: Let's put it this way, if $x=1$ then $\tau_a(x)=ax=$?

Comment: If $x=1$ then $\tau_a(x)=ax=a$. What do I get?

Comment: Homomorphisms take $e$ to $e$.

Comment: @Minh That's right, $\tau_a(1)=a$. But homomorphisms must map $1$ to $1$...

Comment: Okay! That's clear.